# In C++, how do I determine if a class is the last class/child in an inheritance chain? ie on the opposite end of the base class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, children

I'm having problems wording this question concisely, but basically there is a function in a class that may be the last class in an inheritance chain, or it may not be. Inside this function, IF the class-level function is the last in an inheritance chain, a 2nd function will be called. It is much easier to show what I'm talking about than to explain it, so:

Lets say that I have class Z.

Z derives from Y, which derives from X, which derives from W.

All of the classes have a virtual function called Execute().

Z.Execute() requires that Y.Execute() be finished, which requires that X.Execute() be finished, which requires that W.Execute() be finished.

As such, Z's Execute() function looks like:

```
void Z::Execute(void)
{
   Y::Execute();

   // do Z's stuff!
   return;
}
```

Similarly, Y's Execute() function looks like:

```
void Y::Execute(void)
{
   X::Execute();

   // do Y's stuff!
   return;
}
```

And so on down the chain of inheritance.

But Y, nor X, nor W are abstract, and so each can be instantiated, and may or may not be the last class in the inheritance chain.

Here's what I need to know. The last Execute() needs to call DoThisAtEndOfExecute(). DoThisAtEndOfExecute() needs to be called internal to the classes, ie. it will not be public.

So it can't be in X's Execute(), because if the class is a Y, it'll be called too early. It can't be in Y's Execute(), because the class may be a Z. It can't be in Z's Execute() because if the class is an Y, X, or W, the function will never get called.

So is there any way for a class to tell whether it has been inherited FROM? Basically, the equivalent to:

```
if (!IAmTheParentOfSomething)
   DoThisAtEndOfExecute();
```

How is this ever done? I concede that an easier way would be for the function that contains the class to do:

```
X.Execute();
X.DoThisAtEndOfExecute();
```

But that isn't really an option for this code.

Comment: A member function can be protected. This way, it's only available to the declaring class and its derived ones. That's midway between public and private, like you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you want can be achieved if you split Execute into a nonvirtual part and a virtual part. The former will run the latter, then invoke `DoThisAtEndOfExecute`. Like this:

```
class X
{
public:
    void Execute()
    {
        ExecuteImpl(); //That one's virtual, the derived classes override it
        DoThisAtEndOfExecute();
    }

protected:
    virtual void ExecuteImpl()
    {
        //Whatever was in the legacy Execute
    }
}
```

Y and Z override `ExecuteImpl()` and call the base. This way, `DoThisAtEndOfExecute()` runs after the most derived version of ExecuteImpl() is finished, without any knowledge of the actual class.

Comment: I'd make `Execute()` public and `ExecuteImpl()` protected to allow stacking.

Comment: AKA "Template Method".

Comment: AKA [Non-virtual interface](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface).

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to add a default parameter to Execute, and in subsequent calls change that parameter to some other value.

```
class X{
    void Execute(bool isFinal = true);
};
//and so on.

void Z::Execute(bool isFinal)
{
   Y::Execute(false);
   // do Z's stuff!
   if(isFinal){
       // You're up!
   }
   return;
}

void Y::Execute(bool isFinal)
{
   X::Execute(false);

   // do Y's stuff!
   if(isFinal){
       // Y is the last class in this chain.
   }
   return;
}
```

This way, whenever code calls an object's `Execute` method (**without** a parameter), then the method will be told that some outside code is executing it. This also allows you to prevent said termination code from being executed if you so choose, by passing `false` to the method.

Comment: I had thought of that. I was hoping there was some actual built-in functionality.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way of knowing if a class itself is the most distant from a base class (at least not in any way that I can wrap my head around). However, there is always a way for an object to know if it is called externally (as you are aware). I'm wondering if you may be stumbling into an X-Y problem here?

Answer (score 1):

How about moving the // do ...'s stuff! into a seperate function?

```
class W
{
protected:
  void Stuff() { /*...*/ };
  void Finalize() { /*...*/ };
public:
  virtual ~W() {}
  virtual void Execute() { /*...*/ };
};
class X : public W
{
protected:
  void Stuff() { 
    // X Stuff
    W::Stuff();
  };
public:
  virtual ~X() {}
  virtual void Execute() { 
    X::Stuff();
    W::Finalize();
  };
};

class Y : public X
{
  void Stuff() {
    // Y Stuff
    X::Stuff();
  };
public:
  virtual ~Y() {}
  virtual void Execute() {
    Y::Stuff();
    W::Finalize();
  };
};
```

Comment: I think you and Seva Alekseyev are on a similar idea.

Comment: A difference here is that `Execute()` instead of `Stuff()` is virtual, can you explain why you went that route? After all the different implementations of `Execute()` basically avoid the virtual lookup but otherwise do the same...

Comment: I only intended to illustrate the separation in order to achieve the desired behaviour. Imho the non-virtual interface is preferable.